# undo git init when "rm -r .git" doesn't work, Windows

Tags: git, github, git-shell

I am trying to undo a "git init" command in github shell on Windows 8.1.

When I write

> rm -r .git

it says:

> rm : Cannot remove item : You do not have sufficient access rights to perfoem this operation.

It prints it for many files.

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: No way around it: if you want to obliterate a repository, you have to delete its `.git` subdirectory. So the answer is: get the "sufficient access rights".

Answer (score 1):

Ok well, it just wrote it as an error, but when i have done "git init" again it initialized it, so apparently writing "rm -r .git" worked.
The project was also uploaded to github successfully (which is actually what I wanted to do in the first place, undo "git init" was just one of many "undo's" I had to do), so everything is great.

Comment: `git init` can re-initialize an existing repo -- and it *doesn't* wipe out any commits you've made. Can you change the permissions on the `.git` directory?

Comment: I did 'git reset' and I think it wiped out the commits. I am not sure how to change the permissions of '.git' directory, but as I said, so far everything seems ok. Do you think it might be a problem in the future?

Comment: I don't know. You created the `.git` directory by running `git init`, so you *should* be able to remove it. On a UNIX-like system, I'd suggest using `rm -rf` rather than `rm -r`. And in fact, on Linux git creates read-only files under `.git` when you commit things; probably somethings similar is happening on Windows. I think the important question is how to remove the directory. That might be a good question for http://superuser.com/ (though it's likely already been asked). Right-clicking on the folder might get you to a useful menu.